# Catch all domains

Tags: dns, catch-all

Is it possible in DirectAdmin to setup one user account and forward/redirect all incoming domains to this account?

- user = domain1.com
- domain2.com -> domain1.com (domain2.com will stay in the browser address bar)
- domain3.com -> domain1.com (domain3.com will stay in the browser address bar)

This would mean i don't have to add domain pointers all the time with new domains.